# AJAX call doesn't parse JSON

Tags: ajax, json, parsing

I have the following piece of JSON:

```
[
{
    "number": "0",
    "name": "Russell Westbrook",
    "attemptedFG": [
        {
            "x": "333",
            "y": "97",
            "made": "true",
            "assisted": "false"
        },
        {
            "x": "571",
            "y": "389",
            "made": "true",
            "assisted": "false"
        }
    ],
    "attemptedFT": [
        {
            "made": "true"
        },
        {
            "made": "false"
        }
    ],
    "rebounds": "5",
    "assists": "8",
    "steals": "2",
    "blocks": "1",
    "turnovers": "3",
    "fouls": "4"
}
]
```

and I'm trying to parse it with this AJAX call using ReactJS:

```
loadStatsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            this.setState({data: data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
    });
}
```

All the values in the JSON are still stringified after the AJAX call succeeds. The server sends back a response header with 'Content-Type', 'application/json' so I'm not sure why it's not parsing.

Server-side call:

```
app.get('/stats.json', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('stats.json', function(err, data) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: So could you show the **ACTUAL** JSON that was transfered? You can take that from the Network tab of your dev tools.

Comment: Just checked, the actual JSON is the exact same thing.

Comment: Please show a screenshot. Since this is a valid JSON and it **cannot** be parsed into what you explained.

Comment: Sure: http://imgur.com/xjgyKxN

Comment: Now show the stringified values.

Comment: Whoops I just checked the parse output...it seems like nothing is actually getting parsed. I thought the stringified numbers in the non-nested fields were getting parsed but they're actually still strings. I guess now it's a question of why it's not parsing. I updated the original post to reflect my new issue.

Comment: What "not parsing" means?

Comment: Meaning that the AJAX call is succeeding but the JSON data isn't changed/parsed in any way (still stringified). I'll attach a pic of the console logged ajax output: http://imgur.com/hA8IrQZ

Comment: On the screenshot it's a JS object with your data. What exactly "not parsed" means?

Comment: Okay this is all a big misunderstanding. For some reason I thought parsing automatically turned strings into other types. My bad. Thanks for your help zerkms!

Answer (score 0):

When you send a stringified json object from server to client, you need to **parse** that object to readable javascript object. So, you need to parse json in success event of ajax request:

```
success: function(data) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
    }
```

Now `result` is a javascript readable object.